# targeting parent div does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could not able to target parent div when a button is clicked within a div, it suppose to target div with id `itemsMainDiv`

Here is the code used when a button is clicked

```
<div class="Carousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="itemsMainDiv">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4 class="txtlabel">More Books By Same Author</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 CarouselNav" style="margin-top:-20px;text-align: right;"> 
      <button id="leftLst" class="btn btn-primary leftLst"><</button>   
      <button id="rightLst" class="btn btn-primary rightLst">></button> 
   </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="Carousel-inner">
------
------
------
```

[Screenshot of Code comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4wOn.png)

Jquery Code

```
 function click(ell, ee) {
   alert("ell="+ell+", ee=" + ee); 
   var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
   alert("---Parent="+Parent);
   var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide"); 
   ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
}
```

What i have tried :
  `var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent('div:first').attr("id");` //Gives null,

Demo example from : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/zDQkr  On this demo example the scroll buttons are placed below. While from my code,i am trying to place it above carousel.

Comment: To which elements are you binding the click event to? Also, please avoid posting pictures/screenshots of code. Post the actual code instead.

Comment: @Terry   To `itemsMainDiv` i was targeting. I have removed picture. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find nearest parent div with class `Carousel` which you want to target to find.. after putting dis you don't have worry about number of DIVs

```
function click(ell, ee) {
   alert("ell="+ell+", ee=" + ee); 
   var Parent = "#" + $(ee).closest(".Carousel").attr("id");
   alert("---Parent="+Parent);
   var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide"); 
   ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
}
```

Comment: Ohh glad it helps please marked as answer for future reference as well :-) cheers